# How to read characters from a cell array onto a psychtoolbox screen

Tags: arrays, matlab, psychtoolbox

I am setting up an experiment where pairs of words will flash onto the screen in a random order. I have a cell array of my paired words, and I used psychtoolbox to display the words. I keep getting error messages.

I use curly brackets, and try to reference the location of the words, but it never words unless I hardcode the words I want to appear, which won't work because I want the words to appear in a random order for the experiment.

%Here is my array setup:

```
Word1 = {'shaky'; 'salty'; 'dizzy'; 'ideal'; 'jogging'; 'sweater'; 
'brainstorming'; 'weightlifting'};

Word2 = {'easel'; 'shaky'; 'lofty';  'dizzy'; 'whistle'; 'jogging'; 
'weightlifting'; 'sportsmanship'};

DotSpot = { 'top'; 'top'; 'bottom'; 'bottom'; 'top'; 'top'; 'bottom'; 
'bottom'};

Target = { 'fall'; 'fall'; 
'fall';'fall';'active';'active';'active';'active'};

Category = { 'congruent';'incongruent'; 'incongruent'; 
'congruent';'congruent';'incongruent'; 'incongruent'; 'congruent'};

StimList = table(Word1, Word2, DotSpot, Target, Category);
```

%Here is my screen set up:

```
CompScreen = get(0,'ScreenSize'); % Find out the size of this computer 
screen
win = Screen('OpenWindow',0,  CompScreen); %[900 900 1000],
white=WhiteIndex(win);
Screen('FillRect', win, white);
Screen('TextSize',win, 30);
Screen('TextFont',win, 'Courier New');
Screen('TextStyle', win, 1);
```

%Here is where I try to display just one word for now, and it all goes wrong:

```
Screen('DrawText', win, StimList{1,1}  , 500, 500, [0, 0, 0]);
Screen(win, 'Flip'); 
WaitSecs(.5);
KbWait;
```

sca;

Answer (score 0):

The Screen 'DrawText' function is expecting a string, however in your example you are providing it with a cell array which contains a string. Indexing one level further into the cell array will return the string as expected by DrawText:

```
Screen('DrawText', win, StimList{1,1}{:}  , 500, 500, [0, 0, 0]);
```